# Ternary condition in El expression

Tags: jsf, xhtml, el

When I use ternary condition in El Expression I get the eclipse warning message "cannot be result as a member" in the false expression.

`#{sessionController.originalURI != null ?
 sessionController.originalURI : request.contextPath}`

In this case I got the message "contextPath cannot be resolved as a member of originalURI"

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
#{sessionController.originalURI ne null ?
 sessionController.originalURI : request.contextPath}
```

I think it also could be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but reversing the ternary solved the problem

`#{sessionController.originalURI == null ? request.contextPath :  sessionController.originalURI}`

Comment: Tried reversing it back? And what EL version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use `empty`

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html

```
 #{not empty sessionController.originalURI ?
 sessionController.originalURI : request.contextPath}
```

Valid too:

```
#{!empty sessionController.originalURI...
```